# How to split text based on pixel length? (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm currently working with Java Swing and I have some panels that contain text, some of those texts are too long and need to be split into separate rows and I'm not sure what to do to replicate this.

I tried doing it myself but at this point it's safe to say that I don't know what I'm doing

```java
    public static ArrayList<String> splitByPixelLength(String string, int length) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        while (strings.stream().mapToInt(String::length).sum() < length) {
            int processLength = length-1;
            while (string.charAt(processLength) == ' ') {
                processLength--;
            }
            strings.add(string.substring(0,processLength));
            string = string.substring(processLength,string.length()-1);
        }
        return strings;
    }
```

I already have the pixel length of said texts.

Additional example of what I want to do:

```
A man walked into a bar and ordered a drink.
|-----------------------| (imaginary pixel length)
A man walked into a bar
and ordered a drink.
```

Comment: do you mean something like the `JTextArea` offers with [`setWrapStyleWord`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord(boolean)) ?

Comment: You're moving awfully close to doing Text layout which is **incredibly more complex** than you probably think it is. You're almost certainly better of finding a way to let an existing component do that work for you, such as the one suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Only as a hint: The pixel width will depend on the concrete Font used to render the text (among other things). If you really want to dive into this... - I mean, want to go down that rabbit hole, one place to start research is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

Comment: Will I be able to get the accurate width of this component when adding the text to it and using that method?

Comment: (Responding to Hulk) that seems extremely complex, I'll give it a look later

Comment: Can't you just have the component be as wide as the maximum desired width and let the component take care of word wrapping for you? What do you need specifically a `List<String>` for? It seems like there is some [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: @Jake the summary is that on a given client, at runtime, you can use the [`FontMetrics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to get the [`stringWidth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth-java.lang.String-) for a String in a given Font.

Comment: Look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) ad pay attention to the [Drawing Multiple Lines of Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html) section

Comment: JTextArea is exactly what I needed, only issue is that the text is selectable and that disables the functionality of the panel underneath but i'll figure something out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`JTextArea` does the job thanks to JTextArea#setLineWrap(boolean) !